# Actions on Google app not working on phone surface simulator

Tags: actions-on-google

I created a basic AoG app using DialogFlow and it seems to work as I expected in the simulator when using the `Speaker` surface. Yet when I switch the surface to `Phone` it seems to fail an return `Sorry, this action is not available in simulation` every time. Using it on my phone, just returns some search results.

First try is with the `Speaker` surface and the second with `Phone`

[image]

I'll try on my Google Home when I get back from work.

Comment: Did you logged into actions on your phone with the same google account you used to create your app? On the top-right corner there are 3 dots in which **change account**  option is there. You can check your accounts setting there.

Comment: yup, same account

Comment: To help debug, is your app's response payload identical across surfaces? Can you paste the response payload here? Also, just to make sure, have you specified any required surface capabilities in the console overview page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had a similar issue when testing on my phone. I solved by disabling then enabling again the test on device.  On AoG's console, click on the icon of a smartphone in front of a computer besides the speaker icon, on the top right corner. It is weird but when I did this it worked on my phone, maybe you will get the same results.